# How does the MIPS Logical OR Instruction work?

Tags: assembly, mips

Assuming that `$z0` is a register which always contains the number zero.

Then the MIPS instruction `OR $t0, $t1, $t2` puts the bitwise `OR` of `$t1` and `$t2` into the register `$t0`.

Suppose that the register `$t2` contains the number "5".  What is in the register `$t0` after the execution of the instruction or $t0, $z0, $t1

This was a question in a mock exam paper but I'm confused as to how to work it out.  I really need help please.  How would I go about solving it? I'm having trouble figuring out the value of t1 I know how bitwise OR works

Comment: Do you know how bitwise `OR` works? Describe what you did and where you got stuck. Also, please edit your question and give it a meaningful title.

Comment: I edited to improve the question format, but it is difficult to tell what the result would be without the initial value of `$t1`.

Comment: That's exactly my problem I can't figure out the value of t1 hence I'm getting stuck

Comment: It would be the value from `$t1`, but with bits 0 and 2 unconditionally set.

Comment: Why would it do that? Could you explain it please if possible

Comment: Hi just added an extra bit to the question forgot to put in the last bit, could someone please help can't figure it out and my exam is in a few hours only sort of question in stuck on and it's worth a lot if marks. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mips or bitwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534858/mips-or-bitwise)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know WHY register 0 ($z0) is often used in OR instructions:

```
OR $xx, $z0, $yy
```

has the effect that the content of register yy is copied to register zz.

On other processors this is done using the "MOVE" instruction which does not exist on MIPS processors. Assemblers will replace a

```
MOVE $xx, $xx
```

(which does not really exist on MIPS processors) by one of these instructions:

```
OR $xx, $z0, $yy
ADD $xx, $z0, $yy
ADDU $xx, $z0, $yy
ADDI $xx, $yy, #0
SUB $xx, $yy, $z0
...
```

All these instructions simply copy the value of register yy to register xx.

-- EDIT --

You want to know how an OR instruction works in general:

An OR instruction is a bitwise instruction. This means: Two numbers with the same number of bits (e.g. two 32-bit-numbers) are taken and the digits are processed bit-by-bit (and not the complete number).

The OR instruction gives a result of 0 if both "input" bits are 0 and 1 if at least one input bit is 1.

Example:

```
OR t3, t1, t2

t1 = 0x1234
t2 = 0x6789

t1 = 0001001000110100 (binary)
t2 = 0110011110001001 (binary)
---------------------
t3 = 0111011110111101 (binary)

t3 = 0x77BD
```