# Mips or bitwise

Tags: assembly, mips

Assuming that `$z0` is a register which always contains the number zero.

Then the MIPS instruction `OR $t0, $t1, $t2` puts the bitwise `OR` of `$t1` and `$t2` into the register `$t0`.

Suppose that the register `$t2` contains the number "5".  What is in the register `$t0` after the execution of the instruction or $t0, $z0, $t1

This was a question in a mock exam paper but I'm confused as to how to work it out.  I really need help please.  How would I go about solving it? I'm having trouble figuring out the value of t1 I know how bitwise OR works

Comment: `or $t0, $z0, $t1` is unsolvable without knowing the value of `$t1`, or the resulting value in `$t0`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the MIPS Logical OR Instruction work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530364/how-does-the-mips-logical-or-instruction-work)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question though

Comment: That doesn't matter. You should not ask the same question twice. If you want to add more info or otherwise improve the question, then edit the original question. If you still don't get an answer then you'll just have to accept that. Perhaps the question _can't_ be answered.

Answer (score 1):

`a OR 0` is always `a`.

So `0 or 5` is `5`.

`or t0, $z0, #t1` will store value of `$t1` in `$t0`.

Whatever was in `$t1` will be in `t0` now.

Comment: The question says that `$t2` is 5, not `$t1`.

Comment: Whatever was in `$t1` will be in `$t0` now. It doesn't say (from his post) what was in `$t1`. Like you said, unsolvable.